# Enable test client for webapi visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a working webapi. But instead of using fiddler i want to user "Test client" to test that the api really works as they had in the preview version of visual studio 2012.

A webpage saying, this is a api and this api has these method, "press" to try them.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2012 has a asp.net webapi template,
if you use that it has a API menu at right top inside which gives a description on what each API is and how to call it and test it.

If you are a coder have a look at helpcontroller which is generated by Asp.Net MVC automatically, you can tune / enhance it to give a testing tool